# Intelligent automatic block creation in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

I found a template allowing to create new "blocks" in my document via click on a button.
When I click the + sign reported in the attachment, a horizontal line is drawn and a new are for writing text with the same format as the first is create. The + sign is again available and I can keep creating blocks.
What is that element? Where do I create my own?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: They are probably "repeating section" content controls, new in Word 2013. So now you should be able to research them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [bibadia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1379931/bibadia) I confirm they are:

> repeating section content controls, new in Word 2013.